# Force Android Studio to show light bulb

Tags: android, android-studio, code-completion

Say I type the following field

```
field = "I am field";
```

In Eclipse as soon as I place the mouse on `field` it shows me a list of options from which I can select `create local variable field`.

In Android Studio, the lightbulb is a headache for me. Sometimes it appears quickly, sometimes it takes forever to appear.

[image: Example of lightbulb]

Is there a way to force it to appear?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you talking about using `Alt + Enter`?

This link might help:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html

Pressing `Alt + Enter` results in the drop-down menu with correction options in this case:

[image]

Comment: And that's ok but, for example, i not always manage to see exactly where the underlined error is in the code due to discromia. How can i set to ALWAYS show the red light bulb when there is an error?
Yes i know i can change the color of the underline but i want this

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Android studio Settings/Keymap  "shortcut Ctrl+Alt+S"

> search for usage of "Alt + Ent" as below image if its not assigned for any action plz go for No. 2

[Android studio shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Q3P.png)

---

2. In the Android studio Settings/Editor/Intentions.

> Check whatever you want to show Intention in are checked or not as below photo

[Intention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoj4F.jpg)

---

3. Double check no.1 is working fine and you found usage of "Alt + Ent" shortcut

---

[You can find the solution on official Jet brains website]

[Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

[Intention actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the cursor right next to the last letter of the class/method you want to edit, in other hand what worked for me in Android Studio is to use the bar on the right side, 'Outline' and from there get to the part you want to edit and use the tools from Outline or by right clicking on the method that appears in the tree drop down.